# How to find range of a logarithmic function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

How do I find the range of these logarithmic functions?
\begin{align}
& \ln(3x^2 -4x +5), \\
& \log_3(5+4x-x^2).
\end{align}
how should I approach questions like this ?

What I did: I found out the roots of quadratic: i.e. $(5-x)(1+x) >0$
so $(x-5)(1+x) <0$  so it lies between $-1$ and $5$, and then I took log on both sides of the inequality.

Comment: Your approach is a good start. Since log is a monotonic continuous function - you should find the minimal and maximal point in the domain of the function, and apply log to those points to get and upper and lower bounds to the range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only take a logarithm of a number greater than zero.

So you need $3x^2-4x+5 > 0$ in the first case. Completing the square give you $\left(x-\frac{2}{3}\right)^2+\frac{11}9$. We see that the quadratic is always greater than $\frac{11}{9}$ and goes to infinity. Therefore the range is $[\ln\left(\frac{11}{9}\right), \rightarrow \rangle$

For the second one, you want $-x^2+4x+5 > 0$. We first solve $-x^2+4x+5 =0$. This gives $x=-1$ or $x=5$ as you found. Because the coefficient for $x^2$ is negative, this means that the quadratic is positive when $-1<x<5$. The maximum is attained at $x=-\frac{b}{2a}=2$, whith a value of $9$.

So we can make the argument of the log very close to zero but never greater than 9. As $\log_3(9)=2$, the range is $\langle \leftarrow , 2]$.

Comment: thanks for the ans. i did not understand the last line you wrote. how is the range coming in negative when log can not be negative.

Comment: @sonakshi Log can be negative (e.g. log(1/10)=-1, verify on calculator), but you cannot put a negative number in.

Comment: oh right . got it . thhanks

Answer (score 1):

You can view the fact that as $x\to 5$ or $x\to -1$ the functional value is becoming larger and larger i.e. for $\ln(3x^2−4x+5)$ range set is unbounded.

So, also the function is continuous on $(-1,5)$ so there must be a point in the interval where the functional value is the smallest.

Let $f(x)=\ln(3x^2−4x+5)$

$$f'(x)= \frac{6x-4}{3x^2−4x+5}$$

so at $x= \frac23$ the functional value is the lowest and is $\ln(\frac{11}3)$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

In the reals $\log_{b}(p(x))$ is not defined when $p(x) \leq 0$. Where $p(x)$ is a polynomial.